# Is it possible to store a variable and then add more variables seperated by a specific character such as /?

Tags: python

so i'm still new to python and am writing a program that will read in a users input on 1 asset and store it in a text file. However i want to associate more assets with that one specific one without creating a new line.
What i'm trying to say is, is it possible to search for a string in a text file and then add to that string from pythons f.write()

Comment: You can append to a file (open it with append 'a' mode), but you will have an issue if you have more than one asset.  This is because you can only extend the whole of a text file, not single lines within it (applies to all languages).  There are several solutions, and associating assets could be done using a dictionary.  However without seeing some code and data it is difficult to be specific.

Comment: _"What i'm trying to say is, is it possible to search for a string in a text file and then add to that string from pythons f.write()"_ - Yes, it is. Now what is your actual question.